# Features in Clarifai

Tags: machine-learning, clarifai

Does Clarifai provides ***explainability*** (feature) for the model? I am researching on the best ML platform for images and videos hence I came through Clarifai but in my top features I want the platform to have explainability feature as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Clarifai platform does not provide an explainability feature.

There is a contact page you could use to try to request this feature: https://www.clarifai.com/company/contact although I would assume this would be difficult to implement in a platform like this.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me with the answer, much appreciated!!

Comment: No problem @BehjatHuma - this feature is under discussion.  If it gets added I'll try to come back and update this answer.